# vuetify- How do I change arrow color and the size of the icon in vuetify within text-area?

Tags: drag-and-drop, vuetify.js, textarea

I'm trying to make a text input area like this.

[image]

I tried this way

```
        <v-text-field
          label="Outlined"
          placeholder="Placeholder"
          background-color="white"
          append-icon="mdi-arrow-right x-large primary"
          outlined
        ></v-text-field>
```

And it give me this result.
[image]

Issues are

1. Icon doesn't get large enough to fill the entire text-area
2. Can't change the color of arrow stroke
3. What should I do to make this text area also receives file drag and drop?(user might want to type or sometimes drop a file to the text area

Thank you so much.
Hope someone who are well knowledgeable about vuetify could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for part of your question about input design and look you should use provided `slot` from the `v-text-field` component, this way you can achieve more and here is the vuetify documentation about this: [text field icon slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icon-slots)

and to check what other slots is available for this component check this list: [all text field slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#api-slots)

even though using `slot` would achieve a lot more than `prop`, to fully achieve the desired result you might need to overwrite some css styles that you can find by inspecting the element in the browser dev tool to find them out.

I made the look you wanted with the approach described above in the code below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-text-field__details,
.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed:not(.v-text-field--rounded)>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__append-inner,
.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__append-outer,
.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__prepend-inner,
.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__prepend-outer,
.v-text-field--full-width .v-input__append-inner,
.v-text-field--full-width .v-input__append-outer,
.v-text-field--full-width .v-input__prepend-inner,
.v-text-field--full-width .v-input__prepend-outer {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field label="Outlined" placeholder="Placeholder" outlined>
          <template v-slot:append>
            <v-sheet color="red" class="d-flex justify-center align-center rounded-r pointer"  width="50" height="56">
              <v-icon dark>
                mdi-arrow-right
              </v-icon>
            </v-sheet>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

about the drag and drop issue vuetify's `v-file-input` component does not natively support this behavior (for now at least) but you can read the article below to find out how to write this feature in vuetify:

[Step by Step: Custom drag & drop upload component in Vuetify (Vue 2)](https://george-hadjigeorgiou97.medium.com/step-by-step-custom-drag-drop-upload-component-in-vuetify-vue-2-43c99794643d)